# want to know the state of the Notification center whether is in "ON" or "OFF" state in ios5 and ios6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I want to know the state of the Notification center whether is in "ON" or "OFF" state.

As I know every one says to enable that by using

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

BUt i need to get the state either "ON" or "OFF" state.

[image]

I searched google results are:

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone)
{
}
```

and

```
if (launchOptions != nil)
    {
        NSDictionary* dictionary = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        if (dictionary != nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary);

            [self clearNotifications];
        }
    }
```

and

```
if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
    // Do what ever you need to here when notifications are disabled
} else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge) {
    // Badge only
} else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) {
    // Alert only
} else if (notificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound) {
    // Sound only
} else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)) {
    // Badge & Alert
} else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)) {
    // Badge & Sound        
} else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)) {
    // Alert & Sound
} else if (notificationTypes == (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)) {
    // Badge, Alert & Sound     
}
```

But i did not get result  both ios5 and ios6

Please Guide me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In ios6 the notifications center has other options we can set like badges , sounds

Comment: By this line of code we can get the types" UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];" , Instead i want to know the "Notification Center State"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a combination of 2 things you can do to make sure you always know when the user does not have notifications enabled in a specific way.

You must handle both didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken and didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError in your AppDelegate.

Example

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    if (!([[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) || !([[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes] & UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Notice" message:@"You do not have the recommended notification settings enabled for this app."   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Notice" message:@"Your device does not currently have notifications enabled."   delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

FYI: This will always trigger in the simulator so you may want to comment it out until you test on a device as it becomes annoying.